# SQL Server: Cross Referencing multiple columns in 1 table with multiple columns in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, where-clause, exists

I have 2 tables each containing 10 integer fields. I need to retrieve records from table2 where if one of the field values exists in any one of the columns in table1. For example;

[image: table examples]

So if I have  a variable  containing 1 (the id of record in table1) I need sql which will retrieve records 2 & 3 from table 2 because either 3400 or 3500 exists in any of the cat fields in table 2. Hope that makes sense ;-)

Comment: And the question is? Where exactly are you stuck with your query?

Comment: **Question is**: if I have  a variable  containing 1 (Id of record in table1) I need sql which will retrieve records 2 & 3 from table 2 because either 3400 or 3500 exists in any of the cat fields in table 2. Hope that makes sense ;-)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. But you are supposed to have at least tried something where you got stuck and need help. It seems, however, you haven't tried anything, but simply ask others to do the work for you. (Btw. this looks like a bad database design, which is why the query is harder to write than it should be.)

Comment: Did try and got stuck (See my comment on answer below). Thank you for your advice though ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the most efficient way, although a bit cumbersome to write:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2 
where exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t2.cat1 in (t1.cat1, t1.cat2, t1.cat3, t1.cat4, t1.cat5) or
      exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t2.cat2 in (t1.cat1, t1.cat2, t1.cat3, t1.cat4, t1.cat5) or
      exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t2.cat3 in (t1.cat1, t1.cat2, t1.cat3, t1.cat4, t1.cat5) or
      exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t2.cat5 in (t1.cat1, t1.cat2, t1.cat3, t1.cat4, t1.cat5) or
      exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t2.cat6 in (t1.cat1, t1.cat2, t1.cat3, t1.cat4, t1.cat5);
```

More importantly, though, your data structure is bad.  Trying to use multiple columns as an array is usually a bad idea in SQL.  You want a junction table for each of these, where you have one row per id and category.  If you had such a data structure, the query would be much simpler to write and probably have much better performance.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff. I did have something similar to the above.. I was hoping for something more economical which is probably not possible due to the reasons you have given. I can restructure table 1 as per your instructions. 

Basically table 1 contains categories and table 2 products supplied via a feed (no control on structure). I take it by restructuring I can use 'IN'?

Comment: You will still need multiple `in`s because the second table is denormalized.

Comment: Thank again. I restructured the tables and it works perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Table1Ids AS (
    SELECT ID, cat
    FROM Table1
         CROSS APPLY (
             VALUES (cat0), (cat1), (cat2), (cat3), (cat4)
         ) AS CA1(cat)
)
,Table2Ids AS (
    SELECT ID, cat
    FROM Table2
         CROSS APPLY (
             VALUES (cat0), (cat1), (cat2), (cat3), (cat4)
         ) AS CA1(cat)
)
,MatchingRecords AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Table1Ids.ID AS Table1ID
                   ,Table2Ids.ID AS Table2ID
    FROM Table1Ids
         INNER JOIN Table2Ids
             ON Table2Ids.cat = Table1Ids.cat
)
SELECT Table2.*
FROM MatchingRecords
     INNER JOIN Table2
         ON Table2.ID = MatchingRecords.Table2ID
WHERE MatchingRecords.Table1ID = @TheIDYouAreLookingFor
```

Comment: Hi @adrianm thank you for your help.. This isnt working.. I would need to pass it the ID of the record in table 1. I think my original question was not clear. Please see comments of my question ;-)

Comment: @DolphinDan, can't you just just add `WHERE Table1Ids.ID = @TheIDYouAreLookingFor`